# Merge Sort in C with O(N*log[N]) Runtime

Tags: c, algorithm, variable-assignment, mergesort

For an assignment, we are to write the merge sort function in C:

```
sort(int* array, unsigned len);
```

I have the code written and working, but its runtime is `O(N^2*log[N])` which defeats the purpose of merge sort. The reason for the inefficiency is because the merge part is as follows:

```
while(ct1 < len1 && ct2 < len2){
    if(array[0] < array[len1 - ct1]){
        ct1++;
        array++;    // no longer look at that element
    }
    else{
        int position = len1 - ct1;
        int hold = array[position];
        while(position > 0){
            array[position] = array[position - 1];
            position--;
        }
        array[0] = hold;
        ct2++;
        array++;
    }
}
```

where `ct1` is a counter for the left list, `ct2` is counter for the right list, and array is the pointer to the array. Both `ct1` and `ct2` are initially set to zero. Like I said, this works, it's just inefficient because you have to shift everything. I was wanting to split the sub arrays into two temporary arrays before sorting, but you supposedly cannot create arrays whose lengths aren't defined as constants. I should also note that although I can use helper functions, I cannot change the function parameters: there must be a pointer to an array, and the length.

Comment: You need to allocate some memory, say, at most the size of the original array, to use as "scratch" space to do this kind of thing. You are allowed to use dynamic memory allocation, right?

Comment: You can create arrays dynamically. For example int *tmp = (int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int)).

Comment: Modulo taking off the wrong cast on the return value of malloc...

Comment: malloc works, but where exactly is the memory allocated? If it's on the stack then that's best. If not, how do you deallocate it? BTW, the only restriction we were given was that it had to be recursive and we can't use any global variables. Probably only like 5 people in the class even know what dynamic memory allocation is anyway. We were not even given a runtime restriction, but I'm a perfectionist and it irks me to see something run slower than selection sort.

Comment: nvm, got it. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create arrays that are not constant length, google `malloc`.  Merge sort requires use of auxiliary memory to work right.  You must `free` memory allocated by `malloc` when you are done with it.

Comment: Actually merge-sort does not _require_ use of auxiliary memory. It can be done in-place, i.e. there are algorithms known which don't use auxiliary memory, but they are hard and possibly of no practical use.